# Change wordpress port number in nginx

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation with nginx. It's currently use port 80. But I'd like to change it to something else. So I found `/etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress` file and changed the following two lines:

```
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
```

But no matter how I change it, it only works with both port set to 80. I actually don't know what the second line is for. But removing it doesn't seem to make a difference anyway.

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess one is IPv4 and the other is IPv6 config...

Comment: @BigChris Make sense.

Comment: Why you want to change port?

Comment: Good question :)